# How to Handle Exceptions and Error Messages in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, exception, laravel-5

When i get this error:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 620: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

can i handle it with my own flash error message instead of:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong

Answer (score 13):

You have two ways to handle exceptions and show a custom response:

**1) Let the framework handle them for you:**

If you don't handle exceptions by yourself, Laravel will handle them in the class:

```
App\Exceptions\Handler
```

In the `render` method you can intercept the renderning of all the exceptions the framework rises. 
So, if you want to do something in particular when a specific exception rises, you can modify that method this way:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    //check the type of the exception you are interested at
    if ($e instanceof QueryException) {

        //do wathever you want, for example returining a specific view
        return response()->view('my.error.view', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

**2) Handle the exceptions by yourself:**

You can handle exceptions by yourself, with `try-catch` blocks. For example in a controller's method:

```
try
{
     //code that will raise exceptions
}
//catch specific exception....
catch(QueryException $e)
{
    //...and do whatever you want
    return response()->view('my.error.view', [], 500);    
}
```

The main difference between the two cases is that in **case 1** you are defining a **general, application-wide approach** to handle specific exceptions.

On the other hand, in **case 2**, you can define exception hadling in **specific points** of your application

Comment: thank to all 
i tried both  cases and still have  Oooops page 
i'm sure i missed some thing

Comment: try to put a `die('catched');` statement inside the catch block to see if the exception is correctly catched by the code. If not, is the code throwing the exception inside the try block ?

Answer (score 1):

This is work with me fine

```
if ($e instanceof \PDOException) {
    $dbCode = trim($e->getCode());
    //Codes specific to mysql errors
    switch ($dbCode)
    {
        case 23000:
            $errorMessage = 'my 2300 error message ';
            break;
        default:
            $errorMessage = 'database invalid';
    }
   return redirect()->back()->with('message',"$errorMessage");
}
```

Comment: Here you are catching a `PDOException`  so probably your code was rising a `PDOException`, not a `QueryException`  as you stated in the question

Comment: dear Moppo 

i tried also 

if ($e instanceof Exception) {

        //do wathever you want, for example returining a specific view
        return response()->view('my.error.view', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}

and  is working in Handler.php

but try cactch in contlloer dosn't work why

Comment: if you want to catch in the same way in the controller, you should do: `catch(\PDOException $e)`

Comment: thanks Moppo you where very helpfull ,,,so it was all about \ missing in catch

Comment: i did that to catch SQLSTATE[23000]: for duplicate unique item ,,,, is it possible to specify the error

Comment: Sorry but I don't understant what you're asking here. Also, please consider accepting / upvoting my answer if it was useful :)