# Error Messages - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

Can someone please tell me how to make my "Page not found" or something messages? For example if someone writes a link in the browser which do not exist  in my project, not to show the standard error page ( Woops, something went wrong, View [bla.bla] not found ) but page specified by me?

```
<?php



Route::get('sendemail', 'EmailController@sendEmail');

Route::get('test', 'AuthController@getTest');

Route::get('napravisiadmin', 'ClassbookController@getIndex');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']
    ], function () {
        Route::get('login', 'AuthController@getLogin');
        Route::post('login', 'AuthController@postLogin');
    });
    Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@getLogout');


    //Admin
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'auth.admin']
    ], function () {
        Route::group([
            'prefix' => 'admin',
            'namespace' => 'Admin'
        ], function () {
            Route::controller('student', 'StudentsController');
            Route::controller('profile', 'ProfilesController');
            Route::controller('class', 'ClassesController');
            Route::controller('subjects', 'SubjectsController');
            Route::controller('teacher', 'TeachersController');
            Route::controller('marktype', 'MarkTypeController');
            Route::controller('rules', 'RuleController');
            Route::get('{slug?}', 'PageController@getView');
        });
    });
    //Admin


    //Student
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['auth', 'auth.student'],
        'prefix' => 'stu',
        'namespace' => 'Stu'
    ], function () {
        Route::get('{slug?}', 'StuController@getView');
    });
    //Student


    //Teacher
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['auth', 'auth.teacher'],
        'prefix' => 'educator',
        'namespace' => 'Educator'
    ], function () {

        Route::get('edit/{id}', 'AccountController@getEdit');
        Route::post('edit/{id}', 'AccountController@saveEdit');
        Route::get('account', 'AccountController@getView');
        Route::get('class-subject', 'AccountController@getClassSubject');
        Route::get('add-mark', 'AccountController@getAddMark');
        Route::post('mark', 'AccountController@postAddMark');
        Route::get('added', 'AccountController@marksList');
        Route::get('statistics', 'AccountController@marksInTable');
        Route::get('personalemails', 'PersonalEmailController@getView');
        Route::post('personalemails', 'PersonalEmailController@personalEmail');

    });
    //Teacher
});



Route::get('{slug?}', 'PageController@getView');
```

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250180/laravel-5-how-to-handle-error-messages/34250468#34250468) for more info on how to deal with errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create custom error 404 page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#http-exceptions). If someone will enter wrong URL in a browser, he will see that page.

Also, you can redirect user manually to this page with:

```
abort(404);
```

**Update**

I guess the problem is here:

```
Route::get('{slug?}', 'PageController@getView');
```

You're using this three times, try to remove all of them.

The thing is when Laravel doesn't find any routes, it takes `{slug}` and passes it to the `PageController`, so when you enter `http://example.com/sometext`, you will be transferred to the `PageController` with `slug = sometext`.

If you do not want to remove it, check for `slug` inside a controller and if slug means something - good. If not, just `abort(404);` and user will be transferred to an error page.

Also, if you're on 5.2.27 of higher, remove `web` middleware from `routes.php` (it applies automatically, and manual apply can cause errors and strage behavior).

Comment: I'm creating that view, but when i enter wrong url still do not see the view i created. :(

Comment: Did you add `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` view? If you did, what exactly URL you're trying to enter and what exactly do you see?

Comment: yep, i did add it exactly there with that name.

Comment: and getting 
InvalidArgumentException in compiled.php line 14014:
View [pages.somerandomtext] not found.

Comment: Glad I could help. )

Comment: Hi @AlexeyMezenin I saw in one of your other answers yesterday you mentioned about the `web` middleware is applied automatically in `5.2.27`. Where did you read this info as I didn't see it in the release notes here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases#laravel-5.2, maybe it's on the git pages? Please provide a link if possible as it would be good to keep up with changes. Many thanks.

Comment: @haakym, I've answered you here (udated my answer with code): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade - you can download both 5.2.27 and 5.2.24 versions and compare `RouteServiceProvider.php` and `routes.php` files in both archives.

Comment: Oh okay - so you just looked directly at the code then. I thought perhaps you were following a change log or something. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, you can keep track of changes here using Mike Bronner's excellent site: https://laraver.xyz/home

Answer (score 3):

For the "Page not found" 404 error create a view in `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` and it will show when you get a 404 error.

From the documentation:

> Custom HTTP Error Pages
>
> Laravel makes it easy to return custom error pages for various HTTP
>   status codes. For example, if you wish to customize the error page for
>   404 HTTP status codes, create a resources/views/errors/404.blade.php.
>   This file will be served on all 404 errors generated by your
>   application.
>
> The views within this directory should be named to match the HTTP
>   status code they correspond to.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#custom-http-error-pages

You can always go a step further by utilising the exception handler and handling exceptions the way you desire by customising the `render()` method

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#the-exception-handler

For example, if you wanted to handle file not found error, `Exceptions\Handler.php`

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{

    if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException) {
        return response()->view('errors/exceptions/file-not-found', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```